# Converting volume GUID path to device path

Tags: windows, winapi, windows-services

My task is to track adding and deleting disk drives from windows service. I use RegisterServiceCtrlHandlerEx and RegisterDeviceNotification to implement this. My service control handler routine succefully receives SERVICE_CONTROL_DEVICEEVENT control code and handles DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL and DBT_DEVICEREMOVECOMPLETE events for GUID_DEVINTERFACE_VOLUME clsss. By the way windows does not send DBT_DEVICEQUERYREMOVE, DBT_DEVICEQUERYREMOVEFAILED, DBT_DEVICEREMOVEPENDING events to my routine but now i want to solve another problem.

When i receive DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL and DBT_DEVICEREMOVECOMPLETE events and dbch_devicetype is DBT_DEVTYP_DEVICEINTERFACE i can read device name from dbcc_name field of DEV_BROADCAST_DEVICEINTERFACE structure. It looks like this: \?\STORAGE#RemovableMedia#7&331a4e33&0&RM#{53f5630d-b6bf-11d0-94f2-00a0c91efb8b}

I can convert this string to volume guid path using GetVolumeNameForVolumeMountPoint procedure only on DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL event. On DBT_DEVICEREMOVECOMPLETE event GetVolumeNameForVolumeMountPoint returns error 3 (The system cannot find the path specified).

On the other hand during service start i do scan for all volumes in the system with FindFirstVolume/FindNextVolume which returns to me list of volume GUID paths of all volumes.

So if volume exists when my service starts i can receive its volume GUID path. And if that volume will be removed while my service is running then i will receive device name (like \?\STORAGE#RemovableMedia#7&331a4e33&0&RM#{53f5630d-b6bf-11d0-94f2-00a0c91efb8b} ) from 
DBT_DEVICEREMOVECOMPLETE event.

As i wrote above i can not use GetVolumeNameForVolumeMountPoint during DBT_DEVICEREMOVECOMPLETE event to get volume GUID path. So i would like to find a way to convert volume GUID path received from FindFirstVolume/FindNextVolume to device name. I need this to maintain my own list of present removable disk drives in the system.

Please give me some advice on this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So i found no way to retrieve device paths from volume GUID paths returned by FindFisrtVolume/FindNextVolume. Instead i will replace FindFisrtVolume/FindNextVolume with enumerating device interfaces using SetupApi.

Here is steps to do that:

1. Call SetupDiGetClassDevs(&GUID_DEVINTERFACE_VOLUME,NULL,NULL,DIGCF_INTERFACEDEVICE|DIGCF_PRESENT) to retrieve device info set.
2. Enum device interfaces with SetupDiEnumDeviceInterfaces(devinfoset,NULL,&GUID_DEVINTERFACE_VOLUME,idx,&devitf).
3. For each device interface call SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail to retrieve device path.

Unfortunately device path retrieved in this way differs in case from device path which windows passes in DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL and DBT_DEVICEREMOVECOMPLETE events. So we need to normalize device paths when we compare them.

Answer (score 1):

To enumerate devices for building your own device list you can use the [SetupAPI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff550855%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> By using the SetupAPI routines, you can enumerate all devices in the
>   specified device interface class and retrieve the device path of the
>   device.

You call [SetupDiGetClassDevs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff551069%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) first with an appropriate GUID for your device class, e.g. [`GUID_DEVINTERFACE_VOLUME`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff545990%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), then call [SetupDiEnumDeviceInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff551010%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) repeatedly to iterate devices.

Example code showing how to do it:

- [Knowledge base article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/259695) showing it all
- Another description of the process can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff540174%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), have a look for the section *Use the following steps to create a file handle for the USB device.*

The individual devices can be queried for properties (the path is among them) using [SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryProperty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff551967%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Your answer is useful but i need to add some clarification. I tried to use SetupDiEnumDeviceInfo and SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryProperty as you described. But this way i was unable to get device path.  Correct way is to use SetupDiEnumDeviceInterfaces and SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail.